# how to add a LinkedHashSet collection to a JsonObjectBuilder object?

Tags: java, json, collections

I am creating a JsonBuilderObject. My program iterates through a collection and each item of the collection consists of two integer values and three collections. here is the code I have used. I want to add record.matchingTerms which is a LinkedHashSet to my objectBuilder. Can some one provide me with some hints on how to do that?

```
        //start Building a JSON Tree
    JsonObjectBuilder jsonRootBuilder;
    jsonRootBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
    for (Record record : processResultArray) {
        //create json object for each record. 
        JsonObjectBuilder recordJsonBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
        recordJsonBuilder.add("id1", record.id1);
        recordJsonBuilder.add("id2", record.id2);
        recordJsonBuilder.add("matchingTerm", ?); //record.matchingTerms is a LinkedHashSet 
        //creating a json array to preserve matching terms in an array
        //creating a json array to preserve original terms from table one


        //creating a json array to preserve original terms from table two

        JsonObject recordJson = recordJsonBuilder.build();

        //add the record to our array of records 
        jsonArrayBuilder.add(recordJson);
    }

    JsonArray arrayObject = jsonArrayBuilder.build();
    jsonRootBuilder.add("records",arrayObject );
    JsonObject rootObject = jsonRootBuilder.build();
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you just want to know how to add a LinkedHashSet to a JsonObject?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: I have always found such APIs clumsy and arduous. I just create my object, typically a `Map<String, Object>` whose values can be primitives, lists or more such maps, and serialize it using whatever library you have handy; either Spring's choice of jackson, or gson (both work)

Comment: @Bohemian: Thank you for answering. Would you point me to some code sample that  I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

I have always found such APIs clumsy and arduous. I just create my object, typically a `Map<String, Object>` whose values can be primitives, lists or more such maps, and serialize it using whatever library you have handy -
either Spring's choice of jackson, or gson or something else.

Here's a simple example using jackson:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

for ( <each record > ) {
    Map<String, Object> obj = new HashMap<>();
    list.add(obj);
    obj.put("id1", record.id1);
    obj.put("id2", record.id2);
    // etc
}

String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(list);
```

If you want to preserve order of the entries in `obj`, use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

JSON serializers know how to write all objects from the java collections library.